# Qual a origem da palavra "auê"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, gíria, informalidade

Estou tentando descobrir como esta palavra tornou-se conhecida no Brasil. O significado dela é definido no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/au%C3%AA) como

> au·ê <sub>substantivo masculino</sub>
>
> (origem duvidosa)
>
> [Brasil, Informal]  Alvoroço, confusão, tumulto (ex.: *foi um final de semana de muito auê*).

Tanto o Vocabulário Oficial da Língua Portuguesa (brasileiro) quanto o Vocabulário Oficial Português (lusitano) listam *auê*, então já não se pode considerá-la um neologismo. A pronúncia parece sugerir uma origem africana, mas este [blog de umbanda](http://desvendandoaumbanda.blogspot.com.br/2008/08/glossrio.html) diz que

> significa “meu amigo” em iorubá [língua africana]

O que não tem nada a ver com o significado no português brasileiro, indicando que as palavras são provavelmente homônimas.

A referência mais antiga que eu encontrei é [esta música](https://www.vagalume.com.br/rita-lee/desculpe-o-aue.html) da cantora Rita Lee, datada de 1983. As buscas nos Corpi e nas bases acadêmicas não retornaram nenhum resultado útil (a maioria dos resultados veio de erros de digitação ou siglas).

Basicamente, o que procuro descobrir é:

1. De onde veio esta palavra?
2. Como e quando ela começou a ser usada na língua portuguesa?

Comment: Se Priberam não sabe, como que nos, almas pobres, podemos saber? :)

Comment: @Lambie Tenho fé em vocês!

Comment: Será que quando muita gente fala "ué" ao mesmo tempo vira: aué? [brincadeira, mas quem sabe?]

Comment: @Lambie Seria engraçado! hahaha

Comment: Um comentário para aqueles que estão aprendendo o português como segunda língua: prefira sempre "confusão", "alvoroço" ou "tumulto".  "Auê" é não apenas informal, mas também é gíria e, dependendo da tua idade e do contexto, pode soar meio ridículo.  Além do mais, já não é tão usado como há 10 anos. (obs: opinião pessoal)

Comment: @Centaurus, O fato de um termo ser gíria não o desqualifica como pergunta, ué. Até se o uso já baixou. E quem disse que todo aqui vai dirigido a esses indivíduos? Na verdade, gostei da pergunta, por causa justamente do mistério da  origem da palavra.

Comment: @Lambie Não acho que ele tenha desqualificado como pergunta, foi só uma observação mesmo.

Comment: @lambie isso é técnica pra gravação de aglomeração de pessoas, pelo que me lembro falam aua aua aua

Comment: @Centaurus eu nunca ouvi falar de «auê» sequer.

Comment: @JorgeB. É uma gíria brasileira. Já foi tema de uma [música infantil popular nos anos 90](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnwgF__aGh4), e é uma [piada regionalista recorrente](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080414205814AAQj8aL).

Comment: Não me parece impossível de "meu amigo", *auê* passar a servir também de saudação ("e aí, amigão!"), exclamação de alegria, refrão em cânticos (Umbanda é uma religião), festa, animação, e já estamos quase na confusão. Agora, é só especulação. Talvez os ubandistas saibam explicar melhor o uso de *auê* entre eles. Mas [este dicionário de inglês - iorubá](http://www.freelang.net/online/yoruba.php?lg=gb) diz que "friend" é *órèegbèenìkeji!* Não é nesta encarnação que eu vou aprender esta língua.

Comment: @Jacinto Um amigo umbandista havia confirmado, então nem pensei duas vezes que talvez a fonte dele seja tão insegura quanto a que postei. Deveria ter sido mais estrito com o que li. _Mea culpa_.

Comment: Eh pá, mas então tens uma fonte preciosa e privilegiada. Tenta saber como é que *auê* é usado, e desde quando.Esse uso *auê* como 'confusão' pode estar baseado diretamente no uso deles, independentemente de como é que chegou a eles.

Comment: @Jacinto É usado como um vocativo, e às vezes como interjeição. Ele disse não conhecer nenhum caso em que a palavra fosse mais do que acessória.

Comment: Nunca ouvi em Portugal

Answer (score 6):

Não há uma comprovação científica para determinar a origem, mas há evidências da sua utilização e propagação. Na pesquisa no [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=au%C3%AA+significado) traz a origem como **ETIM prov. afr.**

[image: Google: auê significado]

Em dicionários como o [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aue) diz-se que a origem é Maori (indígena da Nova Zelândia)

Essa palavra provavelmente é de origem africana ou indígena e há indícios que **auê** começou a ser utilizada aqui no Brasil pelos indígenas com os cantos típicos de capoeira:

- Paranauê, paranauê, paraná...

Música cantada em tom festivo pelos tupis com referência a um rio, local onde eles se sentiam felizes, protegidos e se reuniam para fazer suas comemorações.

Vocábulário de origem Tupi:

- Paraná significa Rio
- Auê significa bagunça, festa, reverência
- Muito provavelmente herdado das tradições africanas ou indígenas

[DicionarioInformal - Paranauê](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/paranau%C3%AA/15385/)

Como há muita confusão no entendimento das origens dos povos ameríndios, segue os links com maiores detalhes que podem ajudar a esclarecer minha resposta:

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Povos_amer%C3%ADndios
- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_tupi
- http://www.usp.br/cje/entretextos/exibir.php?texto_id=90
- https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/cultura-brasileira/vocabulario-brasileiro-culturas-africanas-influenciaram-nosso-idioma.htm

---

#### Edição:

Muito se criticou sobre minha resposta misturando culturas africanas com indígenas, ainda mais no Brasil que utilizamos o português que tem muitas influências africanas.

Segue um excelente documento demonstrando a utilização da palavra auê em território brasileiro, divulgado em Outubro de 2008 pela Secretaria de Estado e Cultura de Minas Gerais:

http://www.cultura.mg.gov.br/files/2008-outubro-especial.pdf

O texto diz:

A pesquisa pioneira de Aires, ao dar forma escrita a sessenta e cinco vissungos, salvou do completo esquecimento parte fundamental da história cultural brasileira, pois, como ele próprio já observava, **“muito mais do que o produto de três raças tristes, nossa música é o resultado da influência negra”.**

Alguns desses cantos, que se dirigiam à lua, ao trabalho, às coisas simples do dia-a-dia, com “evidente teor religioso”.

Embora  seja  verdadeiro  que o processo de africanização se deva em grande  parte  à  extensão  e  ocupação  territorial,  densidade demográfica  e  antiguidade do povo banto em território colonial brasileiro, não se deve chegar ao extremo de querer “bantuizar” o Brasil como forma
de contrapor o “**ioruba**centrismo” que tem prevalecido nos estudos afro-brasileiros.

Uma  correta  interpretação  das  culturas  negro-africanas,  de  seus códigos,  seu conseqüente resgate do âmbito meramente  folclórico  ou  lúdico,  sua  valorização  e adequada difusão permitirão que o avanço do entendimento da parte do legado **banto** para a formação e sentido do Brasil passe
a ser visível e explícito, **revertendo os estereótipos vigentes em nossa academia**.

Além  do  mais,  o  estudo  lingüístico  desses  falares  afro-brasileiros,  apoiado  pelas informações históricas existentes sobre o período  do  tráfico  transatlântico,  trazem subsídios importantes para a configuração do mapa etnolingüístico africano do Brasil. Aqui está a prova do que nos dizem os vis-
sungos  sobre  a  presença  dos  ovimbundos, povo originário de territórios do antigo reino de Benguela, em terras de Minas Gerais.

Papai auê mamãe, ongira oenda mondongo auê a.

Sigo  o  caminho  do  meu  povo  e  auê  –  me choro e alegro.

Comment: Uma pena que só vi esta resposta agora. Uma dúvida que me bateu agora: se a origem é africana, então como que os índios tupis cantavam? Deveria ser indígena. não?

Comment: Ramon, o Brasil foi um dos únicos países das Américas a receber africanos de todas as origens. Essas tradições normalmente são herdadas com o passar do tempo e a mistura dos povos.

Comment: Mas os índios tupis não são africanos, e a mistura entre eles e os africanos, se houve, foi minima. Africanos foram trazidos ao Brasil como escravos apenas porque os índios brasileiros resistiram à escravidão dos colonizadores. Como pode uma tradição africana ter começado no país pelos indígenas?

Comment: Ramon, muitos africanos também eram indígenas antes de serem escravizados e mesmo com essa mistura mínima já é o suficiente para a integração de culturas. Além de que, não se sabe como os tupis se originarão e há muitas teorias de que nascemos de uma só origem. Em dicionários como o [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aue) diz-se que a origem é Maori, ou seja, não há uma comprovação científica para determinar a origem, mas há evidências da sua utilização e propagação. Em nenhum momento eu afirmei que os índios tupis são africanos.

Comment: Acho que esta resposta mistura indígenas sul-americanos com escravos africanos de maneira confusa. Desculpa, @n3uRoQuiLa, mas não consigo propor uma edição que eu ache que melhore isto.

Comment: Para você todos os africanos são escravos? Não existe tribo na África? Eu não citei a palavra escravos na minha resposta. E se você não achou boa a mistura de africanos com indígenas, porque não colocou fatos que ajudem a melhorar a resposta ao invés de simplesmente criticar? Vou adicionar mais detalhes sobre os povos ameríndios na resposta.

Comment: Não leve para o pessoal, n3uRoQuiLa. Assim como @ANeves, estou muito interessado na resposta e com dificuldades de compreensão. Ninguém está acusando ninguém de nada. "Indígenas" do continente americano receberam este nome porque se acreditava ter chegado às Índias, enquanto os nativos da África já eram conhecidos e, por isto, não levaram este nome. Quando você mistura ambos na mesma resposta, não fica claro se a origem é dos povos americanos ou dos povos africanos.

Comment: Embora ambas as culturas sejam de desconhecimento das nossas análises historiográficas (que descendem de métodos eurocêntricos), existe uma distinção clara entre ambos os tipos de povos, e um certo consenso de que houve pouca mistura entre eles, uma vez que os africanos no Brasil tinham suas tribos desfeitas e os ameríndios eram reclusos em seus próprios territórios.

Comment: Ramon, suas observações foram muito úteis para a discussão pois você sempre coloca o seus argumentos de forma clara e objetiva, não estou levando para o pessoal não, mas como é uma pergunta com muitos poréns e pontos de vista é natural que haja um debate mais intenso e é bom se seja assim para todos podermos esclarecer e entender melhor. Eu ainda acho que tem muito da cultura de tribos tanto para africanos, maoris e tupis com uma ligação muito forte. Fiz alguns ajustes na minha resposta graças as pessoas como você que participam ativamente e minha resposta jamais é a definição da verdade.

Comment: @Ramon e n3uRo, nenhuma das fontes indicadas na resposta diz que *auê* seja de origem africana. Segui o link do Collins, e o que encontro é uma interjeição de dor ou espanto neozelandeza; que tem isto a ver com a palavra brasileira? Dizes que o Google diz que *auê* é de origem prov. africana; segui o link e não encontrei essa informação. Segui o teu link do dicionário informal, e não diz lá o que tu afirmas: não diz que *auê* signifique bagunça ou que seja "provavelmente herdado de tradições afircanas". Os outros links na tua resposta não dizem nada acerca de *auê*.

Comment: É, por favor não liguem a quando eu escrevi "escravos"! Foi falha minha. Leiam por favor "gentes africanas", como corrigiu bem o Ramon.

Comment: @Jacinto clica no link do Google, logo no inicio já aparecerá as definições e logo abaixo tem uma seta "Traduções, origem das palavras e mais definições" clique nela. Na minha resposta está como africana OU indígena, pois não há comprovações da raíz dessa palavra.

Comment: Quando cito os links fala-se muito sobre a influência do tupi e africana na nossa cultura e linguagem. Essa palavra pode ter se originado de uma mescla de culturas. Isso é apenas uma teoria.

Comment: n3, já tinha clicado no teu link; não encontro nada disso; a primeira coisa que me aparece é "Auê - Dicionário inFormal". Talvez dependa da região em que estás. Vê se consegues linkar diretamente a página onde aparece a origem. Todos sabemos que há influência africana e ameríndia no português. Mas isso não justifica afirmar que uma palavra em particular seja uma mescla das duas. É preciso informação mais concreta.

Comment: No caso de "paranauê", _paraná/paranã_ significa rio grande ou mar (dependendo do lugar), mas o _(g)üê_ se se lhe pospõe é um marcador de vocativo, conforme o Pe. Lemos Barbosa: algo como "ó rio!" ou "ó mar!"

Answer (score 0):

Duvido que a origem seja africana ou indígena. A palavra é recente no Brasil. Da década de 1980.
Se por acaso existe em algum dos inúmeros dialetos indígenas ou africanos, é coincidência. As palavras que herdamos deles são antigas na nossa língua
Também não pode vir de awe, embora essa seja uma ideia bem interessante.
Awe é um espanto reverente.
Auê é zorra, zuêra, uma bagunça, uma confusão.
Auê surgiu com gíria de surfista. Provavelmente palavra inventada.

Comment: Betinha, bem-vinda ao Portuguese StackExchange! Uma dica: no Portuguese StackExchange, tentam-se usar fontes nas respostas, para fortalecê-las. O Houaiss data 1970; ademais, por ser uma palavra tão exclusiva da língua falada informal, é dificílimo datar sua origem precisamente! Disseste algo errado também, o Houaiss data "muvuca", uma palavra africana, de 1976, inclusive mais recente do que "auê". Outro ponto: "[...] Provavelmente palavra inventada". Que palavra não é inventada? Quarto ponto: por que não pode vir do inglês "awe"? Agora entendeste por que das fontes? Bem-vinda de qualquer modo!

Answer (score -2):

Aue tem origem em awe inglês que significa espanto, temor e reverência.

Comment: As palavras serem semelhantes, e até a coincidência de significados, não prova uma estar na origem da outra.

Comment: Isto é, Jose Frajtag: tens fontes que indiquem essa suposta origem? Como baseias esta resposta? Com boas fontes, ficas com uma boa resposta. :)